# Dependencies didn't get inherited from parent project

Tags: java, spring, maven

I want to use maven multi module to separate my project so i start to make a commons dependencies.

But when I try to use a dependency package defined in the parent project into a child module maven project `import  org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;`

Eclipe say  `The import org.springframework cannot be resolved`

**Parent** `pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ao.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>ao-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>ao-commons</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>  

  </dependencies>

</project>
```

**Child** `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>ao.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>ao-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>ao-commons</artifactId>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>

</project>
```

Comment: How are you building the project? From the parent and on the command-line? In an IDE?

Comment: @Tunaki I didn't build anything yet i'm just following a youtube tuto ... i didn't run anything

Comment: How can you have errors if you didn't run anything?

Comment: Compilation error I guess. you don't need to run a project if he miss some packages to see the errors

Comment: To see compilation errors, you need to compile. So are you in an IDE? How did you start the compilation?

Comment: Im on eclipse he detect copmilation error

Comment: It is very hard to see what could be wrong without that much info. Try to 1. Update m2e 2. Enable workspace resolution (right click > Maven > Enable workspace resolution) 3. Refresh the project (right click > Maven > Update project, and tick the "Force update" checkbox) 4. Clean the thing (project > clean).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do 2 things here.

Firstly, in your parent pom, add all your dependencies within the `<dependencyManagement>` tag. This will make sure that the dependencies are available for the child to use. So now this is how your parent pom will look.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>ao.parent</groupId>
  <artifactId>ao-parent</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>ao-commons</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
     <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>  
     <dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

</project>
```

Secondly, in your child pom, you will have to explicitly include the dependencies by just specifying the `groupId` and `artifactId`. Since the version will be handled by the parent pom. So now your child pom will look like this.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>ao.parent</groupId>
    <artifactId>ao-parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>ao-commons</artifactId>

  <packaging>jar</packaging>


   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>  
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

The reason you will have to to it this way is because when you have a multi-module project with a parent pom and one or more child pom's the dependency's version will be dealt with in the parent pom and the child pom will simply inherit it. Also, when you include any dependency in the parent pom, maven will simply understand that those dependencies are available for the child to use. But, if the child has to use any of those dependencies, then the child has to explicitly specify the dependencies by using just the `groupId` and the `artifactId`.